# WPF, What's the best way to store a constant to be used at startup?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that accesses a database instance.  I develop on my personal machine and the application will run on another machine and database instance.  Is there a way or best practice for storing the instance name outside of the WPF application that I can read upon app startup?  Currently I have comment and uncomment the database instance name as I move from machine to machine.  I would like to have something stored on the local machine that I can just read when the application is launched.

Here is what I currently do:

```
try
        {
            if (sqlConn != null)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }

            strConnection = "Data Source=" + strDBInstance + "; Initial Catalog=NBFoodPantry;Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets = True";
            //strConnection = "Data Source=CASS-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=NBFoodPantry;Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets = True";
            //strConnection = "Data Source=KENTS-WORK-PC\\CASS_SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=NBFoodPantry;Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets = True";

            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@strConnection);
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string strMsg;

                WriteErrorLog(strErrorLogFile, "ConnectToDatabase", ex.Message, false);
                strMsg = "ConnectToDatabase: SQL Open failed.  Please make sure that you database ";
                strMsg += "instance and name are correct.  Also make sure that the SQL engine is running.";
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strMsg;

            WriteErrorLog(strErrorLogFile, "ConnectToDatabase", ex.Message, false);
            strMsg = " ConnectToDatabase: failed with error, " + ex.Message + ".";
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
        }
```

Comment: You can create a static readonly field in your application. But then question arises, how you will communicate from one machine to another. **Edit:** If you just need to use the constant to load the connection name for the database, you can store that in the web.config, or load it from any API. But that is not the best approach.

Comment: you should post a snipp code of your effort

Comment: See [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN. Your DB connection string should be an application setting (in App.config, not Web.config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what application settings are designed to handle. Under the properties node in your project, open the settings.  This has built in support for connection strings:

[image: Settings Dialog]

Then you can access the settings in your code by its name:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString
```

All of this is stored in your App.config, which you can modify on various machines to have different values.

Comment: #Clemens and #John Koemer -- This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: @Cass you might also want to look into Debug/Release or other transformations with this tool https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms